# Count sum of spaces between first element and a specific element prolog

Tags: prolog

Basically trying to figure out how you would make a predicate where given two parameters, a list and a number, you would sum up the amount of spaces from the first element to the specific letter.

Example, say 'w' is the letter, given the statement

```
h1([e,w,b,a,w,w,c], 10)
```

would return true since 10 = 1+4+5 where 1,4,5 are the distances from element 0 and would return false if not 10.

Heres what I have so far

```
h2(List, H) :- sum(List,0,H).

sum([],TotalCount,TotalCount):- !.
sum([w|T],CurrentCount, TotalCount) :-
  NewCount is CurrentCount + CountSince,
  sum(T, NewCount, 0)
sum([_|T], NewCount, 0) :-
  CountSince is CountSince + 1,
  sum(T, NewCount, CountSince).
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried and ask a specific question.

Comment: @lurker edited to show what I have so far, and what do u mean by ask a specific question.

Comment: A couple of issues: (1) in your second `sum/3` clause, `CountSince` is singleton, and (2) in your third clause you have `CountSince is CountSince + 1` which will *always* fail since `CountSince` cannot ever be the same value as `CountSince+1`.

Comment: I would try again using `findall/3`, `nth0/3` and `sumlist/2` instead of trying to build all this machinery by hand.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, you can solve this problem with three lines of code, using `findall/3` and `sum_list/2`. Here the code:

```
h2(L,E,V):-
    findall(P,nth0(P,L,E),LP),
    (   LP = [] ->   false;
    sum_list(LP,V)).
```

I wrote `h2/3` and not `h2/2` to make it more modular (i.e. you can pass the element you want to find to the predcate). Since you want `false` as answer if the element is not in the list, i've added an if statement to check if the list from `findall/3` is empty. If it's not, simply sum the elements with `sum_list/2`.

```
?- h2([e, w, b, a, w, w, c],f,V).
false

?- h2([e, w, b, a, w, w, c],w,V).
V = 10
```

Comment: Excellent! I would omit the condition and be content with `h2(..., f, V)` unifying `V` with 0 though.